# Change the background color of the layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Android Studio 0.4.6
minSdkVersion 10
targetSdkVersion 19
```

I have an activity called `ReadingLamp` and a Relativelayout called `activity_reading_lamp.xml`.

I am programmatically trying to set the layout to a different background color.

In my onCreate and set the content view to this layout.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading_lamp);
```

I try and get the root view by doing the following:

```
mActivityBackground = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Then later in my app I want to change the color so I do like this:

```
mActivityBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0cf5ff"));
```

However, the above line doesn't do anything to change the background.

I have also tried doing the following:

```
mActivityBackground = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_reading_lamp);
```

Where am I going wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you post activity_reading_lamp.xml ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically change the layout color of layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094766/programatically-change-the-layout-color-of-layout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have declared, `setContentView(R.layout.activity_reading_lamp);` in your `Activity`. Then you should look for the view you want to change the background color. It has to belongs to `R.layout.activity_reading_lamp`.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.declared_inside_reading_lamp);
```

Then you can call

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that all layouts in your `activity_reading_lamp.xml` have transparent background

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which background you need to set. For example, you can make id for the parent layout on your activity then do:

```
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id."your parent layout id and not your activity name");
parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to make a transition to the new color try this:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") private void tintColor(View rootView, String newColor) {
    // currentColor can be given as a new parameter or set as a field
    ColorDrawable[] color = {
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(currentColor)),
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(newColor)) };
    TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        rootView.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
    } else {
        rootView.setBackground(trans);
    }
    trans.startTransition(ANIMATION_TIME); // ANIMATION_TIME : time in milliseconds
}
```

The code accepts hex color strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```